# How can i detect BlankLine that Scanner has receive?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to get data form text files ,and I use Scanner to get data form text file.
 It's profile save pattern

```
name
status
friend
friend
.
.
(Blank line)
```

Blank Line is separate each profile.(friend will looping till next line is a Blank Line)

```
john 
happy
james

james
sad
john
```

And i code to get file form text like this

```
try{
    Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new FileReader("testread.txt"));
    while(fileIn.hasNextLine()){           
         String line = fileIn.nextLine();
         String linename = fileIn.nextLine();
         String statusline = fileIn.nextLine();
         println("name "+linename);
         println("status "+statusline);
         while(/*I asked at this*/)){
             String friendName = fileIn.nextLine();
             println("friend "+friendName); 
         }                              
    }
}catch(IOException e){
    println("Can't open file");
}
```

What condition that I should use to detect blank line between profile?

Comment: homework tag is deprecated see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated?cb=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement custom function like below which will return you `nextLine` if it is not empty.

```
 public static String skipEmptyLines(Scanner fileIn) {
    String line = "";
    while (fileIn.hasNext()) {
        if (!(line = fileIn.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
            return line;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check your `scanner.nextLine()` for a Newline `"\n"` (I mean `""`, because `nextLine()` does not read `"\n"` at the end of any line).. If its equal, it will be a blank line..

```
if (scanner.nextLine().equals("")) {
    /** Blank Line **/
}
```

BTW, there is a problem with your code: -

```
while(fileIn.hasNextLine()){          
         String line = fileIn.nextLine();
         String linename = fileIn.nextLine();
         String statusline = fileIn.nextLine();
```

You are assuming that your `fileIn.hasNextLine()` will confirm about the next three lines being `not null`.

Everytime you do a `fileIn.nextLine()` you need to check whether it's available or not.. Or you will get exception...

***EDIT: -** 
O.o... I see there you have handled exception.. Then there will be no problem.. But still you should modify the above code.. It doesn't look pretty..

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){

    if(scanner.nextLine().equals("")){

            // end of profile one...

       }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After checking for an existing line with `scanner.hasNextLine()` method, you can use this condition:

```
String line = null;
if((line = scanner.nextLine()).isEmpty()){
   //your logic when meeting an empty line
}
```

and use the `line` variable in your logic.